# How to set multiple style attributes in d3 at once

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, d3.js

I would like to clean up and abstract some of my css declarations but am not able to figure out how to do so. I want to define an `obj` and pass that as a argument to the `style` method.

My `package.json` has `"d3-selection": "1.4.0",`

Current code:

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";

var tooltip = select("body")
      .append("div")
      .style("position", "absolute")
      .style("visibility", "hidden")
      .style("background-color", "white")
      .style("padding", "5px");
```

Ideal:

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";

const styles = {
  "position": "absolute",
  "visibility": "hidden",
  "background-color": "white",
  "padding": "5px"
} // `styles` would be imported from an external `styles.js` file.

var tooltip = select("body")
      .append("div")
      .style(styles);
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

I have tried using the `d3-selection-multi`, but keep on getting errors

Selection Multi

```
import { select } from "d3-selection";
import { select as selection } from "d3-selection-multi";

const styles = {
  "position": "absolute",
  "visibility": "hidden",
  "background-color": "white",
  "padding": "5px"
} // `styles` would be imported from an external `styles.js` file.

var tooltip = selection("body")
      .append("div")
      .styles(styles);
```

Error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Comment: d3-selection-multi uses `selection.styles()` as opposed to the `selection.style()` of plain d3-selection.

Comment: Ah yes.. typo in the question! Updated.

Comment: Not sure if styles allow that and i am not familiar with React.. But in general, I would write a function to convert the json to string format.. and use the "attr "
Something like .attr("style","stroke-width:5;fill:red")

Comment: @gsuresh92 - docs to the `d3-selection-multi` - https://github.com/d3/d3-selection-multi#selection_styles